# Angular2 HTTP request - set cookie error

Tags: angular, cookies, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get some data from a rest api and for that I'm using http module of angular2. My problem is that I'm getting an error "Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" " when I send the http request.

Here is my code.

```
getChannels(endpoint: string): Observable { 
  let headers= new Headers(options.headers) 
  headers.append('Accept','application/xml')
  headers.append('Cookie', this.cookie);

  let reqOpt = new RequestOptions({headers: headers}) 
  return this.http.get(endpint, reqOpt ).map((response) => {
    return response;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to XHR specifications, `cookie` header is forbidden.

[from documentation:](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)

> These are forbidden so the user agent remains in full control over
>   them. Names starting with `Sec-` are reserved to allow new headers to
>   be minted that are safe from APIs using fetch that allow control over
>   headers by developers, such as XMLHttpRequest.

So, why you aren't using JWT (JSON Web Token) instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to send a cookie to connect to Mirth Api Framework. Using request i can do that, but i would like to use http and use Observables.

Comment: I'm not sure about Mirth Api Framework requirements, but if you are not familiar with jwt, I can assist you with using it along observables and http...

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm noob with angular2 and having some problems to understand observables and how to chain services

Comment: I was noob a while back about them too, They are easy and pretty great. a good starting point is their documentation on ReactiveX website.
http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html and http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html
good luck. :)